# Simple Count of Rows that contain a date within a given Date Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, row, date-range

I have tried to research an answer but cannot seem to find the right solution.  I am looking to simply count the number of rows that are in this sheet that contain dates from any given quarter. For example, Simply count the rows where a student took an exam in the 2nd quarter (October 1 2023 and December 31, 2023) or better yet (>=K4 and <=L4).

I use `COUNTIFS` but it counts each cell

I use `SUMPRODUCT` and it gives me a 0 because some of the rows/cells don't have dates in that range.

Any help would be appreciated!

I have tried:

```
=COUNTIFS(D3:I30, ">= " & J4, D3:I30, "<= " & K4)
```

but that gives me the total cells, I just need the rows.

`=SUMPRODUCT` give me either a 0 or an #NA

Comment: Have you tried the answer posted on yesterday?

Comment: Oh my word thank you all!  This takes it into a different dimention that I didnt consider for. The first and third solutions worked but the second solution gave me a #NAME error.  I guess even though I am using 365 I do not have the lambda functiton enabled?

Comment: The third worked, bt the second didn't worked because for that you need to enable the office insiders.

Comment: I am very happy with the solution offered (the first) but for those who may want to know in the future, how do you enable office insiders?

Comment: Open **`Excel`** --> **`File`** --> **`Account`** --> Click on **`Microsoft Insider`** --> Click on Beta Channel --> accept terms and conditions and press `OK`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for this information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using one of the followings:

[image]

---

Use `MMULT()` function as mentioned by [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) Sir:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MMULT(((D3:I30>=K4)*(D3:I30<=L4)),{1;1;1;1;1;1})>0))
```

---

Or If applicable, means if you are presently using `MS365` and while writing this formula have enabled the `Office Insiders` then using `ETA LAMBDA` i.e. without `LAMBDA()` construction using `BYROW()` function:

```
=SUM(--(BYROW((D3:I30>=K4)*(D3:I30<=L4)>0,OR)))
```

---

Or, If not enabled then:

```
=SUM(--(BYROW((D3:I30>=K4)*(D3:I30<=L4)>0,LAMBDA(x,OR(x)))))
```

---